# performing full text searches on huge amount of docs

Tags: mysql, performance, search, full-text-search

Suppose you have huge amount of documents, a few millions, and more coming.
Suppose you have to publish them on a website with hundreds of thousands of daily pageviews, and suppose you have to let the visitors perform searches on all the documents.
What is the best way to store/retrieve the documents? And to perform searches on them?

Currently the system i'm talking about uses swish-e to create indexes for static html files.
These files are served as static content to the users.

Is this a good way?

What's the best solution between a database to store and search the contents (MySQL) and store the contents in static files and use a tool to index them and perform searches (Swish-e)?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get your site indexed properly, you can try installing [Google Site Search](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/) and be done with it.

If you want to have your own search, consider using [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/). IMO, it's far superior to MySQL Full-Text Search.

Comment: I get my site indexed properly, it's a matter to know if i'd better switch to a faster system (if it exists) to perform internal searches or not.